# Tracking Changes done to a Class without using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, change-tracking

I am in need of tracking any changes done to a complex model (a very complex model must I say with all kinds of relationships). Once I have identified these changes, I must save them into a separate table, in order to be approved by an administrator at a later stage.

I've tried using the change tracker of Entity Framework and have even tried to customize it but it has just been giving me problem after problem.

What do you suggest I could use in order to track these changes, which does not involve Entity Framework?

---

UPDATE: I ended up solving this by creating my own custom checker. Took more time but in the end it was more worth it as I had total control over the changes.

Thanks for you opinions,

Steve :)

Comment: You've tagged your question with `entity-framework` and yet you explicitly don't want to use it?

Comment: Read up on the "Unit of Work" pattern (which is what EF and other ORMs implement for this purpose). Reference version would be from Martin Fowler in *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*.

Comment: EF can give you all changes on a plate. Why not use it? BTW This question is rather broad. If you could show the customizations you mention we'd have a starting point.

Comment: Maybe [CSLA](https://github.com/MarimerLLC/cslaforum/issues/208)? I used it before EF which does far more IMO.

Comment: There is no way on Gods Green Earth you are going to be able to efficiently "write your own" entity tracking system...I suggest just using EF.

Comment: `There is no way on Gods Green Earth you are going to be able to efficiently "write your own"` ? EF uses Reflection... so we will use Reflection. Meta programming is a thing and should not be beaten down upon. Yes EF has a VERY complex and mature Unit Of Work but the OP just wants state tracking. You could just open the source code of EF, Look at the code of how they Reflect properties and what collections they use to track changes. Bam, God Loves You, Efficiently :D

Comment: The reason Im trying to move away from entity framework is that it does a fantastic job in tracking changes to objects like strings or ints but when facing many-to many relationships its tends to get too complex.

Comment: I usually found that if something becomes complex and tedious while using a framework.. it probably means I am doing something incorrectly. Got to take what you doing with a bit of critique. I found when I changed my question, I usually realised what was wrong, fixed it and worked allot better. You may think its an oversight, or Microsoft trying to torture you.. but they deal with extremely complex models (for example CRM) So I am sure they wouldn't want to make it complicated to work with.

Comment: For folks that might find your answer to this question useful, could you provide some information about your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not providing code example. As commented this is more of an idea (to broad for this Exchange) but it is a high level way that I have done before. Back when "reflection" was highly frowned upon we called it "meta data" but essentially employed reflection - and for that reason, today it is known as meta programming.

Your problem, is a lovely use case for **meta programming**. Reflection used to be very slow in "80's" only due to low memory and restricted CPU.

- Serialises, such as JSON use reflection or the infamously slow XML (but not anymore)
- Dependency Injection is the mother of meta programming
- Helpers like auto mapper is mostly reflection too.

Today it has been highly optimised and works extremly well due to excellent computational power. As long as you do not write hacky code, or try to optimise it further you will be OK. You should trust the framework and compilers for that.

You can do some fancy things such as intercepting changes but that can get quite complex. To keep it a bit simpler all you have to do is follow a bit of DDD

Your classes should only allow changes via the properties you expose. Each Set or operation that mutates the state can then be sent your lovely state tracking code.

in NET 4.5 reflection is really fast and meta programming is already used in Dependency Injection allover the show.

To remember changes use an optimised collection like maybe a Dictionary or HashSet. Depends on your needs. Using `GetType` store that as the key and the value can be the new value, or a class that hold metadata like. Old Value, New Value, Version (for rolling back), etc etc.

Once you get that going in your class you then move all the logic into singleton, and define some generic methods that you will reuse on all your "entities"

Comment: My downvote: just as questions can be too broad and unclear (like this question), answers can be. Answering broad/unclear questions tends to be a fruitless effort. Also, reading this I have serious doubts if this is gonna work at all. I think it'll clutter the code big time.

Comment: Oh right. Yes you are correct. This particular Q&A is more suited for the code review exchange. Although, on there you require an idea in code already. I agree this is high level principle. But I answered it because I have done this several times, for a few companies. Plus, I am not ashamed of reflection anymore because Microsoft encourages it, made it fast and easy to use. They use it in many places of the NET CLR. Thank you for commenting. At least I know the -1 is more about SO guidelines and not me being grossly incorrect (or partly) Thank you for giving me the opportunity to elaborate. +1